# I am not able to display image on a canvas using a button click

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am not able to add an image to a canvas, what I want is when clicked on the button the file manager opens and then I can select an image and click open to load the image

this is my code:-

```py
canvas=Canvas(width=200, height=200)
browse=Button(text="Browse")


canvas.place(x=440, y=80)
browse.place(x=480, y=300)

global photos

def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                  title = "Select a File",
                                  filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                "*.jpg*"),
                                               ("all files",
                                                "*.*")))

   image = (Image.open(filename))
   resize_image = image.resize((200, 200))
   photos = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
   canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=photos)


browse.config(command=browseFiles)
```

Comment: can you show what actually happens because from glance this looks fine

Comment: `global photos` should be inside `browseFiles()`.